# Disable "add to cart" for Guest User

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, login

How can I Disable the "add to cart" when user is not logged in.

Comment: Have you tried googling for same? You will get so many answers for same.
Try this,  http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2013/02/14/how-to-hide-price-from-non-logged-in-users-guest-users/

Comment: Do you wat to hide Add to cart button OR just redirect to Login page if not logged in while adding to cart ?

Comment: i want to Redirect to Login page if not logged in while adding to cart

Comment: try free module https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/hide-price-and-add-to-cart-for-guests-users.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below module, which is provide to not login user hide product price.

https://github.com/Tartilas/Magento-hideprice

Also if you want to do via pragmatically than check with below event. Using below event to set price equals to zero

first event :

```
<catalog_product_get_final_price>
           <observers>
             <hideprice_catalog_price_observer>
               <type>singleton</type>
               <class>Wsc_Postcode_Model_Observer</class>
               <method>hidePrice</method>
             </hideprice_catalog_price_observer>
           </observers>
         </catalog_product_get_final_price>
```

second event :

```
<catalog_product_collection_load_after>
  <observers>
    <hprice_catalog_price_observer>
      <type>singleton</type>
      <class>Wsc_Postcode_Model_Observer</class>
      <method>hidePriceCatalog</method>
    </hprice_catalog_price_observer>
  </observers>
</catalog_product_collection_load_after>
```

simply check if user is not logged in (Observer.php) and set final price equals to zero

```
public function hidePrice($observer){
            $event = $observer->getEvent();
            $product = $event->getProduct();
            if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
                $product->setFinalPrice(0);
                $product->setPrice(0);
            }

    }

    public function hidePriceCatalog($observer){
        $products = $observer->getCollection();

        if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
            foreach( $products as $product )
            {
                $product->setFinalPrice(0);
                $product->setPrice(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

And on phtml we can also check :

```
if($_product->getFinalPrice() == 0 || $_product->getPrice() == 0){
       echo '<span class="login_for_price"><b>Login to See Price</b><br></span>'; return; }
```

I hope its work for you.

Answer (score -1):

In Magento version 2 you can disable checkout for guest user from admin panel->store->configuration->sales->checkout.

Comment: questions is magento 1 version

Comment: You mention magento version in tag also mention in description because now magento 2 is released and developer used magento 2 for development.

Comment: You can achieve this by doing custom coding.

Comment: M1 question ...